# Handle Connection state at boot of device in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am making dynamic Register Receiver for Listening connection of internet in android 7.1 and it is starting correctly When internet connection is changed, I handled in OnReceive() method in NetworkChngeReceiver but When I boot device I can't handle connection of internet, my application is started at startup When device is booted, how can I listen connection of internet at boot time of device?

```
private BroadcastReceiver mNetworkReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate((Bundle savedInstanceState)){
mNetworkReceiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver(context, this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();

   // Register mMessageReceiver to receive messages.
  registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}

   public NetworkChangeReceiver(Context context,Activity a){

        try {
            c = context;
            activity = a;
            wifiScanReceiver = new WifiScanReceiver(context);
            wifiManager = (WifiManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When device booting there won't be happening any change of network connection status so won't trigger NetworkChangeReceiver. We can get a connection status by ConnectivityManager.